# Custom Doxygen Parameter

Tags: doxygen

I want to do "global" variables in Doxygen.
For example we have @param commands to specify parameter.
I want to add new one as a "@param_global" I want to specify the global variables.
How can I do that ?

Comment: I think it is sufficient to document the global variable, but without an example and the doygen version used etc. it is hard to tell. Interesting might also be the `\var` command (see the doxygen documentation https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdvar) .

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Doxygen version 1.8.11 I'm using for C programming language.

Comment: Doxygen version 1.8.11 is a bit old (December 2015) the current version is 1.8.18 From your comment is is unclear whether or not your problem still exists / you could solve it, when not please provide an example.

Comment: I haven't been able to solve it yet, I have reviewed the command \ var command but it is not what I was looking for

Comment: So an example ....

Comment: I dont understand what example? I want to do global variables like @param commands. 
How can I special parameter added in my doxygen or what can I use the global variables

Comment: With example is meant the source code + the documentation commands used to reproduce the problems / to indicate the indicate what you are missing (possibly with an image). At the moment it is, to me, unclear what you would like to have.

Comment: I found this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783300/how-to-documenting-global-dependencies-for-functions I want to do like this but what is the "Doxygen configuration file" where can I add some special codes?

Comment: The "doxygen configuration file " is the Doxyfile and contains the settings like `ALIASES` etc. In the doxywizard the can be found unde "expert"

Comment: @albert I added in Expert>Project>ALIASES but I have an error like this:
error: Illegal alias format `ALIASES += global_START="
Globals

\1
: \2
"'. Use "name=value" or "name(n)=value", where n is the number of arguments error: Illegal alias format `ALIASES += global_END="
"'. Use "name=value" or "name(n)=value", where n is the number of arguments

Comment: I added new topic here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62594036/illegal-alias-format-aliases
I get the codes in this topic:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783300/how-to-documenting-global-dependencies-for-functions

Comment: What did you do to solve the warning you got? Reading the documentation (e.g. doxygen.nl/manual/custcmd.html#custcmd_complex) as you have 2 arguments (\1 and \2) but where is your `{2}` part?  (Reformulated due to wring brackets).