# Illegal alias format `ALIASES '

Tags: doxygen, doxygen-wizard, doxywizard

I added below codes into doxywizard ALIASES but I get error. How can I solve this?

```
ALIASES += global_START="<dl class=\"params\"><dt>Globals</dt><dd><table class=\"params\">"
ALIASES += global_{2}="<tr><td class=\"paramname\">\1</td><td>: \2</td></tr>"
ALIASES += global_END="</table></dd></dl>"
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Error message:

> error: Illegal alias format `ALIASES += global_START="
> Globals
>
> \1
> : \2
> "'. Use "name=value" or "name(n)=value", where n is the number of arguments error: Illegal alias format `ALIASES += global_END="
>
> "'. Use "name=value" or "name(n)=value", where n is the number of arguments

Version: `1.8.11`

**SOLUTION**

I manually added in doxyfile like this:

```
 ALIASES                = ALIASES += global_START="<dl class=\"params\"><dt>Globals</dt><dd><table class=\"params\">"
                          ALIASES += global_{2}="<tr><td class=\"paramname\">\1</td><td>: \2</td></tr>"
                          ALIASES += global_END="</table></dd></dl>"
```

And open the doxywizard, ALIASES field look like this: (every line must added seperately)

```
ALIASES
+=
global_START="<dl class=\"params\"><dt>Globals</dt><dd><table class=\"params\">"
global_{2}="<tr><td class=\"paramname\">\1</td><td>: \2</td></tr>"
global_END="</table></dd></dl>"
```

Comment: It looks like you wrote "ALIASES+=` in the Alias field, but in the ALIASES field of the doxywizard you should not write `ALIASES+=` this is done automatically by doxygen.

Comment: I try this and edited question please look again

Comment: Please complete the example in the question so we have the input that matches the output also publish the exact text of the Doxyfile in the question (maybe use first `doxygen -u -s` to strip away the comments) as it looks a bit like an extra `\` is present..

Comment: Solution doesn't look like correct to me, `ALIASES                = ALIASES += global_START="< ...` is incorrect, should be: `ALIASES                = global_START="< ...` (wil also the linses `ALIASES` and `+=` from the cut and pasted `ALIASES` field in the doxywizard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an answer, but too long and complicated for a comment.

I was not able to reproduce result sas indicated in the question, my input and output:

Source code used:

```
/// \file

/**
 * @brief Port state and port index value assign with Modbus Input Register
 * The application receives in this parameter the zero-ba..
 * @param[in] portRole This parameter get the role of the port
 * @global_START
 *
 * @global_{bExampleTwo, Second Description Here}
 * @global_END
*/
void fie(int portRole);
```

Doxyfile used:

```
ALIASES += global_START="<dl class=\"params\"><dt>Globals</dt><dd><table class=\"params\">"
ALIASES += global_{2}="<tr><td class=\"paramname\">\1</td><td>: \2</td></tr>"
ALIASES += global_END="</table></dd></dl>"
```

Resulting image (detailed part:

[image]

Comment: I manually added in Doxyfile.txt file like you It works now thank you  for your attention

Comment: Good that this problem is solved. Must have been something strange in your doxygen configuration file.

Comment: When I change in the doxyfile and open the doxywizard it looks different.Maybe I have to add like that ( I add in topic)

Comment: I understood what we had to do to add it through wizard correctly. That's why I updated the question please check